# What is faster: custom taxonomy or serialized post-meta for db retrieval? (over 60,000 posts)

Tags: custom-taxonomy, post-meta, taxonomy, wpdb

I have a search plugin that can search serialized metadata as well as categories (for multi-checkbox).

Is there any advantage to using serialized post metadata instead of creating a custom taxonomy type?

Simply: taxonomy vs serialized metadata.
What is faster for db retrival??
Large number of posts, over 60,000

Comment: Terms (term names and slugs) are [indexed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html), while meta values are not, hence if you can, use taxonomy and not metadata - specially those serialized. But performance isn't my expertise, thus I posted this as a comment rather than an answer.